# Trying to add border around tumblr container theme

Tags: html, css, border, tumblr

I am trying to add a border to a tumblr theme but can't seem to do so. Usually i just add the code `border: 5px solid #fff;` to the container part of the theme and it works but with this one it isn't working.

```css
.cont {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left:0;
    opacity: 0.6;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:273px;
    height:374px;
    background: url('{image:sidebar bg}') repeat ;
    border-radius:0px;
    opacity:1;
    z-index:9999999999;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

Comment: Please enter the code in the question and not as image. Not everyone can copy that.

Comment: .cont {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left:0;
    opacity: 0.6;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:273px;
    height:374px;
    background: url('{image:sidebar bg}') repeat ;
    border-radius:0px;
    opacity:1;
    z-index:9999999999;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

Comment: Please share the HTML to this corresponding css

Comment: @gcldhvney I meant the HTML or try linking us to the site.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work for me: https://jsfiddle.net/lharby/Lanbk1es/

I've added a grey background to the body so you can see the border.

Also note that  `background: url('{image:sidebar bg}') repeat ;` won't work in jsfiddle as this is part of the tumblr templating language. If you want to see an actual image, you will need the full url: `https://66.media.tumblr.com/1234.jpg` etc.

Here is the full css:

```
body {
   // added to show white border on .cont element
   background: #999999;
}

.cont {  
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0px;
   left:0;
   opacity: 0.6;
   overflow:hidden;
   width:273px;
   height:374px;
   background: url('{image:sidebar bg}') repeat ; // this won't render in jsfiddle
   border-radius:0px;
   opacity:1;
   z-index:9999999999;
   -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
   border: 5px solid #fff; // added border as per the comment above code.
```

}

Also you are setting opacity at 0.6 in the css and then later for the same element 1.0, so the 0.6 will be overwritten.